# MySQL count row with group by dayofweek including zero result

Tags: mysql, count, zero, dayofweek

I've made a query to retrieve daily data this week. i hope of getting a table like as follows:

```
  hari   total  finish   issue  
 ------  ------  ------  --------
 1       0       0         0
 2       0       0         0
 3       1       0         1
 4       1       1         0
 5       0       0         0
 6       0       0         0
 7       0       0         0
```

this my query:

```
SELECT  DAYOFWEEK(`waktu`) AS hari,
COALESCE( (COUNT(*) ), 0) AS total, 
COUNT(IF(`jarak`<70,1,NULL)) AS finish, 
COUNT(IF(`jarak`>70,1,NULL)) AS issue 
FROM `presensi` 
WHERE WEEKOFYEAR(`waktu`)=WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY hari;
```

but, the query is not show zero result. how to show all day of week including day with emty data?

Comment: your hari data doesn't support it now, now does it

Comment: Dayofweek() returns value from 1-7. not 0 to 6

Comment: @Excel yes, i have create a mistake. but, my point is return of all day.

Answer (score 0):

You only have 7 days of the week, so this is easy enough to do with a `left join`:

```
SELECT dow.dow  AS hari,
       COUNT(p.waktu)  AS total, 
       SUM(`jarak` < 70) AS finish, 
       SUM(jarak > 70) AS issue 
FROM (select 0 as dow union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
     ) dow left join
     `presensi` p
     on p.DAYOFWEEK(`waktu`) = dow.dow and
        WEEKOFYEAR(`waktu`) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY dow.dow;
```

Comment: he may need a dummy table for left join that includes week of year / day of week as a helper table

Comment: @DrewPierce i have try it.
whit this code

SELECT 
 h.`id` AS id_dummy,
        COUNT(p.waktu)  AS total, 
        SUM(p.`jarak`< 70) AS finish, 
        SUM(p.`jarak` > 70) AS issue 
 FROM hari_dummy h LEFT JOIN
 `presensi` p
 ON DAYOFWEEK(p.`waktu`)= h.id
GROUP BY id_dummy ;

Comment: @mosleim . . . Ooops, the `where` condition should be in the `on` clause.

Answer (score 0):

i have solve my problem. i create a dummy table with list of day(idea from @drew-pierce).
this my query:

```
SELECT 
  h.`id`, 
  COALESCE(d.total,0) AS total, 
  COALESCE(d.finish,0) AS finish,  
  COALESCE(d.issue,0) AS issue
FROM
  hari_dummy h 
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT 
    DAYOFWEEK(p.waktu) AS hari,
    COUNT(p.waktu) AS total,
    COUNT(IF(p.`jarak` < 70, 1, NULL)) AS finish,
    COUNT(IF(p.`jarak` > 70, 1, NULL)) AS issue 
  FROM
    `presensi` p 
  WHERE 
     WEEKOFYEAR(waktu) = WEEKOFYEAR(NOW()) 
  GROUP BY hari
 ) d 
ON d.hari = h.`id` 
ORDER BY h.id ASC;
```